# Configuring SAML with LDAP in spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

Is there a way to configure LDAP as IDP provider for SSO.
I used the spring saml demo project (which shows sso circle as idp provider) and able to configure two apps (sps) with SSO.

Now, I want to use the LDAP for populating user data (for authentication and autherization). Is there a good demo or tutorial to learn and follow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I use SAML (so can't speak to that), but I use the following for configuring my LDAP (AD) in Spring.

```
<security:ldap-server
    url="${ldap.url}"
    manager-dn="${ldap.manager.user}"
    manager-password="${ldap.manager.password}"
/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider
        user-search-base="${ldap.search.user.base}"
        user-search-filter="${ldap.search.user.filter}"
        group-search-filter="${ldap.search.group.base}"
        group-role-attribute="${ldap.search.group.filter}"
        group-search-base="${ldap.search.group.attribute}"
    />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already set this LDAP in my application.But, I want IDP to use this details for authentication and authorization. Currently IDP using the credentials provided during registration.

Comment: I used Shibboleth as IDP and configured LDAP in login.config file. Now it is working as desired :)